# converting time to seconds and back

Tags: python

I have a date (I suppose it is in UTC, but may also be in localtime)
I would like to convert this date to seconds ... and back (seconds --> date)

So, after some research in Stackoverflow I came up with those two functions:

```
def UTC_to_sec(utc_time):
    """
    convert time in UTC to seconds. 
    input: s string
    output: float
    """
    return time.mktime( datetime.datetime.strptime(utc_time, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").timetuple() )

def sec_to_UTC(s):
   """
    convert time in to seconds  to UTC.  
    input: time in seconds (float)
    output: string

    """
   return datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(s).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

# test with mydate="2010-09-15 08:31:00"
print "time ", mydate, " (UTC) --> (",UTC_to_sec(maydate), ") [s] --> ",sec_to_UTC(UTC_to_sec(mydate)), " (UTC)"
```

The result is:

time  2010-09-15 **08**:31:00  (UTC) --> ( 1284532260.0 ) [s] -->  2010-09-15 **06**:31:00  (UTC)

Does this mean `mydate` was in localtime and not in UTC?

I only get the correct result when modifying the function `sec_to_UTC()` as follows:

```
datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(s-time.altzone).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

`time.altzone` being in my case  -7200 [s]. But this is a nasty workaround.

My question is: What makes the aforementioned date-seconds-date conversion depends on the timezone?

Answer (score 1):

The culprit is `time.mktime()`.

From [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.mktime):

> This is the inverse function of localtime(). Its argument is the struct_time or full 9-tuple (since the dst flag is needed; use -1 as the dst flag if it is unknown) which expresses the time in local time, not UTC.

Comment: Oh very true! So that means I need to correct the return value of mktime by adding the value of  time.altzone, right?